# uwsgi master and emperor modes and binary upgrade

Tags: uwsgi

I've been digging around for some time on this and have not been able to find any clear answers.

First.

What are the benefits of running uwsgi with **both** the --master and --emperor options?

I know it is recommended to always use --master, however I have not been able to find any benefit of using both over just using --emperor.

Second.

Is there a way to upgrade the binary of uwsgi **"on the fly"** in the same way you are able to upgrade nginx's binary?

It seems you have to do a complete stop and start of the uwsgi processes for it to pick up the new binary. In which case requests stop being processed.

If these have been discussed previously, I apologize. If there are any links to previous discussions, I would appreciate them to take a look at.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the Emperor with the Master is only required if you want advanced logging or alarms for the Emperor. Generally it is not needed. Every time you make a graceful reload of the stack, you end with binary patching: https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Management.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I must be missing something then. If I run with both --master and --emperor and reload after a binary upgrade. The sock file gets deleted for the sites emperor is managing, but not recreated. If I only run with --emperor and do a reload after the upgrade, it seems to reload fine, but `/usr/local/sbin/uwsgi --connect-and-read /run/uwsgi_stats.sock` still reports the previous version of the binary.